# Making a Custom accordion jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am making a custom accordion. My problem is I don't know how to `slideUp` the div that is being `slideDown` once I click on the other header with there div is not yet being `slideDown`.

Here is my code:

CSS:

```
.grid-l1{ width: 500px; height: auto; min-height: 500px; overflow: hidden; padding: 10px; background: #000; }
.header{ width: 100%; text-align: left; background: #fff; color: #000; font-size: 14px; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold; padding: 5px; cursor: pointer; margin: 0px !important; }
.level-box{ width: 100%; height: auto; overflow: hidden; background: #ededed; padding: 10px; display: none; }
.box-a1{ width: 100%; height: auto; overflow: hidden; margin: 5px 0px; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="grid-l1">
    <div class="box-a1">
        <h2 class="header">
          Header
        </h2>   

        <div class="level-box">
          <label>Test Input</label>
          <input type="text">
        </div>
    </div> <!-- box-a1 -->
    <div class="box-a1">
        <h2 class="header">
          Header 2
        </h2>   

        <div class="level-box">
          <label>Test Input</label>
          <input type="text">
        </div>
    </div> <!-- box-a1 -->
    <div class="box-a1">
        <h2 class="header">
          Header 3
        </h2>   

        <div class="level-box">
          <label>Test Input</label>
          <input type="text">
        </div>
    </div> <!-- box-a1 -->
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('body').on('click', '.header', function() {
    $(this).closest('.box-a1').find('.level-box').slideToggle();
});
```

Should I use `slideToggle` ? I will appreciate every responds you guys will be making. And feel free to teach me, I'm still a newbie in jQuery world :) Thanks a lot Sir.

Comment: there are a bunch of solutions here , but what they are all missing is on click you want to stop all animations first , then slide up all .level-box that is not (this), then slide down this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```js
$('body').on('click', '.header', function(e) {
    $('.box-a1').find('.level-box').stop().slideUp();
    $(this).closest('.box-a1').find('.level-box').stop().slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.grid-l1{ width: 500px; height: auto; min-height: 500px; overflow: hidden; padding: 10px; background: #000; }
.header{ width: 100%; text-align: left; background: #fff; color: #000; font-size: 14px; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold; padding: 5px; cursor: pointer; margin: 0px !important; }
.level-box{ width: 100%; height: auto; overflow: hidden; background: #ededed; padding: 10px; display: none; }
.box-a1{ width: 100%; height: auto; overflow: hidden; margin: 5px 0px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid-l1">
    <div class="box-a1">
        <h2 class="header">
          Header
        </h2>   

        <div class="level-box">
          <label>Test Input</label>
          <input type="text">
        </div>
    </div> <!-- box-a1 -->
    <div class="box-a1">
        <h2 class="header">
          Header 2
        </h2>   

        <div class="level-box">
          <label>Test Input</label>
          <input type="text">
        </div>
    </div> <!-- box-a1 -->
    <div class="box-a1">
        <h2 class="header">
          Header 3
        </h2>   

        <div class="level-box">
          <label>Test Input</label>
          <input type="text">
        </div>
    </div> <!-- box-a1 -->
</div>
```

Comment: Sweet. Thanks Nizam. You save me. Thank you Sir

Comment: this does not work - if div is already open - I click it and expect it to close

Comment: Oh I see thank you for double checking it Selby. So how do this bug be fix ? Thanks

Comment: Hello Nizzam it seems like there are still bugs on it. It do closes an open div but the accordion effect is being remove with your edited code :) Correct me if I'm wrong Sir :) Thanks

Comment: I have corrected it. As pointed by @ScottSelby, you need the stop function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.siblings()` to slide up the other boxes:

```
$('body').on('click', '.header', function() {
    var $box = $(this).closest('.box-a1');
    $box.siblings().find('.level-box').stop().slideUp();
    $box.find('.level-box').stop().slideToggle();
});
```

As @ScottSelby points out in a comment, the animations should be stopped with `.stop()` before staring new ones. The user would have to click fast, but animations on the same element queue up if they are not stopped.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4hc7L09/1/)

Comment: Thanks Sir. I've also tried this. This works too . Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just `slideUp` all the level box at initial start. And `slideDown` active element that was clicked.

```
$('body').on('click', '.header', function() {
  $('.level-box').slideUp();
  var current = $(this).closest('.box-a1').find('.level-box');
  if (current.is(':visible')) {
    current.slideUp();
  } else {
    current.slideDown();
  }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/metallurgical/79jk1eoh/1/)**

Comment: if I click an open div I would expect it to close

Comment: @ScottSelby : yeah sure, i'm just realize that. thanks