# Display the accordion dynamically and the first accordion open and close previous accordion when click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am getting the records from the database and I have to display that records in accordion. I am able to displaying the records. Now what I am doing is, I have to display the first accordion open and when clicking on then close the previous accordion if open.

Currently, on page load all the accordion showing closed and when I click on accordion then it's not closing the previous accordion.

**js**

```
$('body').on('click', '.ac-title', function(e) {
    $('.accordion-wrapper').find('.ac-content').stop().slideUp();
    $(this).closest('.accordion-wrapper').find('.ac-content').stop().slideToggle();
});
```

**php**

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {   ?>
    <div class="accordion-wrapper">
    <div class="ac-pane">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="ac-title" data-accordion="true">
         <span><?php echo $cat_name;?></span>
        <i></i>
        </a>
        <div class="ac-content">
            <!--contnet-->
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

**css**

```
.accordion-wrapper{max-width: 500px;width: 100%;margin: auto;text-align: left;border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;}
.ac-pane { margin-bottom: 15px;  color:#000;border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;}
.ac-pane:last-child { margin-bottom: 0;border-bottom:none; }
.ac-content { display: none; }
.ac-title {color: #000;display: block;padding: 12px;background-color: #fc5c49;font-size: 20px;position: relative;}
.ac-title span{color: #fff;}
.ac-title img {float: right;font-size: 20px;width: 30px;}
.ac-title i:before {content: ""; background-image: url('../images/plus.png');
width: 20px;height: 20px;background-size: cover;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: center;position: absolute;right: 30px;top: 15px;}
.active .ac-title i:before {content: ""; background-image: url('../images/minus.png');
width: 20px;height: 20px;background-size: cover;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: center;position: absolute; right: 30px;top: 15px;}
.ac-content {margin-top: -1px;padding: 15px;font-size: 17px;}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Close accordions if other accordian is open in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186993/close-accordions-if-other-accordian-is-open-in-jquery)

Comment: @Awais, I am getting the accordion dynamically. I have Static code which is working for me but dynamically not working

Comment: @Awais, I am not using a jquery accordion. This is a custom accordion.

Comment: May be this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30204588/making-a-custom-accordion-jquery

Comment: @Awais, Yes in the last refer link help me to solve my issue but not 100%. only one issue is remaining and that is how to display the first accordion open? Now all the accordions are showing closed.

Comment: Can you update your updated code in question!

Comment: @Awais, Code updated.

Comment: On document load just add the class `active` with `display:block` style property, then remove that on you above click function

Comment: I added active class but it is effecting all the accordions because of the loop.

Comment: Try jquery first selector `:first Selector` https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

Answer (score 0):

@updatedQuestion: To display only the first row you could do like:

```
$count = 0;
while ($stmt->fetch()) {?>    
<div class="accordion-wrapper <?php if(!$count) echo 'active'; ?>">
<div class="ac-pane">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="ac-title" data-accordion="true">
     <span><?php echo $cat_name;?></span>
    <i></i>
    </a>
    <div class="ac-content">
        <!--contnet-->
    </div>
</div></div>
```

And before closing the php tag at the end: $count++;

Comment: I tried your code it's working but not 100% because active class is still showing when I click on second accordion.

Comment: I added <div class="ac-pane <?php if(!$count) echo 'active'; ?>"> and  added script   $(this).closest('.subserviceAcc').find('.ac-pane').removeClass('active'); which is solved my issues

Answer (score 0):

Hi bro after wrapping your while in ma div use this jQuery code

**PHP**

```html
<div class="accordion-wrapper-main">
     <?php while ($stmt->fetch()) {   ?>
        <div class="accordion-wrapper">
        <div class="ac-pane">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="ac-title" data-accordion="true">
             <span><?php echo $cat_name;?></span>
            <i></i>
            </a>
            <div class="ac-content">
                <!--contnet-->
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
        <?php } 
    ?>
    </div>
```

**JS**

jQuery(".accordion-wrapper:nth-child(1) .other-hold").addClass("active");